# WaterlineJS/SailsJS: Query "contains" array

Tags: sails.js, waterline

how do i accomplish multiple value inside query 'contains' ? 
eg.

```js
{
    name: {
        contains: [
            'west',
            'lob'
        ]
    },
    address : {
        contains: 'york'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want `name` to contain _both_ values, or _either_ value?

Comment: name contains either value

Answer (score 0):

Having checked up on it via the gitter channel you need to do...

If you wanna use contains then you need to use LIKE! if you want a straight match then use a normal query.

```
Model.query("SELECT whatever FROM MyTable WHERE someFielding LIKE '%THEVALUE%'", function(error, myRows) {
  // do some stuff
});
```

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query